# Hbase API migration from onprem to Bigtable GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hbase, bigtable

There are multiple application which is using Hbase data in on-prem.
Now we are planning to migrate the Hbase data to GCP Bigtable.

Post migration of this Hbase to Bigtable. The multiple applications need to consume the data from Bigtable now .
So What will be the high level solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform an offline migration, you may check with this [comprehensive guide](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/37758?catalog_rank=%7B%22rank%22%3A140%2C%22num_filters%22%3A0%2C%22has_search%22%3Afalse%7D&locale=ja&parent=catalog) which explains clearly step by step.

Or if you want to execute an Online migration, there is a [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkTPEDhhS1c) that goes through the specifics of what needs to be done.

Also you may consider Taking [HBase table snapshots and import them to Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/migrate-hbase-on-google-cloud-to-bigtable#migrating-hbase)

Reference: [**HBase to Bigtable Migration**](https://medium.com/google-cloud/hbase-to-bigtable-migration-strategy-using-snapshots-lab-37d3e6569def).